# Nginx, unicorn and multiple rails apps in subrirectories

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, unicorn

I'm messing around with aws, and want to deploy multiple apps to my free tier aws account.

I'd like to have nginx point to "ec-2-site.com/first-app" and "ec-2-site.com/second-app.

Here are my current config files (basically guess and checking from [this railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/335-deploying-to-a-vps?view=asciicast)

```
upstream unicorn_chaos {
  server unix:/tmp/unicorn.chaos.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

upstream unicorn_blog {
  server unix:/tmp/unicorn.blog.sock fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
  listen 80 default deferred;

  location /chaos/ {
    #server_name http://ec2-50-16-81-170.compute-1.amazonaws.com/chaos;
    root /home/deployer/apps/chaos/current/public;

    location ^~ /assets/ {
      gzip_static on;
      expires max;
      add_header Cache-Control public;
    }

    try_files $uri/index.html $uri @unicorn;
    location @unicorn {
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_redirect off;
      proxy_pass http://unicorn_chaos;
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
    client_max_body_size 4G;
    keepalive_timeout 10;
  }

  location /blog/ {
    # server_name example.com;
    root /home/deployer/apps/blog/current/public;

    location ^~ /assets/ {
      gzip_static on;
      expires max;
      add_header Cache-Control public;
    }

    try_files $uri/index.html $uri @unicorn;
    location @unicorn {
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_redirect off;
      proxy_pass http://unicorn)blog;
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
    client_max_body_size 4G;
    keepalive_timeout 10;
  }
}
```

Here is the error I'm getting:

```
 nginx: [emerg] named location "@unicorn_chaos" can be on the server level only in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/chaos:23
```

Obviously that @unicorn_appname directive shouldn't be there, but where should it be? Am I going bout this all wrong?

Thanks

Comment: A naive question but is the entire code given above inside `http {}` block?

Comment: How did you solve this?

Comment: I didn't solve it. This was a personal aws server and I haven't been working on it that much since then.

Comment: There's a topic I answered my self, take a look:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18134046/multiple-rails-4-app-using-nginx-unicorn/18161635#18161635

Answer (score 1):

I didn't check the railscast but I've found some problems in your configuration.

First is on line 50 you misspelled the address.

Second is that you should put named locations out of the locations.

Your hierarchy looks like this

```
server
    location app1
        try_files @unicorn
        location @unicorn
            proxy_pass unicorn_app1
    location app2
        try_files @unicorn
        location @unicorn
            proxy_pass unicorn_app2
```

Try this

```
server
    location app1
        try_files unicorn_app1
    location @unicorn_app1
        proxy_pass unicorn_app1

    location app2
        try_files @unicorn_app2
    location @unicorn_app2
        proxy_pass unicorn_app2
```

The important is to keep their names **unique**, and put them in the same *server* level.